# Install unmanaged package avoiding B2C capabilities

Tags: package, person-accounts, unmanaged-package, b2c

I have built an unmanaged package and I need to install it onto another Salesforce org.

*We made a terrible mistake* by enabling **person accounts**, and now I can't install the package because the destination org needs to enable person accounts, but that's exactly what I DON'T want.

I've reviewed every line of code and found no reference to any extra fields. Also, I took away all permissions in the profiles, and so on.

Any guidance or help would be kindly appreciated!

Thanks
Bernardo

Comment: 1. Ditch the "unmanaged" package (is this really a 1GP "unmanaged package" or did you mean a 2GP "unlocked package"?). 2. Use the same metadata to create a new 2GP managed package or unlocked package depending on your needs...

Comment: I don't think I understand the difference between 1GP, 2GP or unlocked packages, so I will study about them.. thanks for the prompt response!